# WebRTC audio playback in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio-recording, webrtc, web-audio-api

I'm working on [this app](http://nathanathan.com/ShowAndTell/) and the audio recording feature comes close to working in Chrome for Android, but it fails for a reason I haven't yet identified. (It works property in Desktop Chrome and the latest Firefox). The actual recording seems like it might be working, as microphone access is requested and I think audio blobs are created. However, I can't play the audio back.

I'm using WebRTC to record and the demo [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) also fails to play back audio in Android Chrome. This seems like it's a bug in the browser, but I'm wondering if there is a work around. It seems like there could be since the WebRTC demo [here](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) successfully streams audio to other clients from Android Chrome. And I'm wondering what the root of the problem is. Is the recording not properly created, or is the audio element just incapable of playing it back? I haven't been able to play back audio created from the Windows Chrome version of my app in Android Chrome, so I suspect there could be a playback issue.

EDIT: I've determined that there is a playback issues since I was able to play audio recorded in Android Chrome Beta (that I could not play on the device) in desktop Chrome. Could using an AudioContext instead of an Audio element for playback avoid the issue or do they both have the same limitations?

Answer (score 1):

Try it on Beta Chrome for Android.  Audio input is working in Beta, but not yet in stable.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome Beta and I still was not able to play back audio. However, I saved the audio blob as a data uri and I was able to play it back in desktop Chrome (with some glitches in the sound), so it seems this is primarily a playback issue. (I'm not sure if Chrome beta actually does anything different when recording. I was having an issue with my jsZipped data getting corrupted when I saved it in the current Chrome which prevented me from testing my recording in dektop Chrome. It seems Chrome Beta has fixed whatever was causing the zips to get corrupted.)